# Getting Hex between range?

Tags: powershell

How can I get all possible hex numbers between given range?

For example;

```
getting all hex numbers from 0x00 through 0xFFF
getting all hex numbers from 0xAB thorugh 0xFEFF
..
..
```

and so on...

Comment: 0x00..0xFFF | foreach {Write-Host $_.ToString('X3')}  You do not need the ToString().  The default in PS for displaying integers is decimal (not hex).  So storing number as decimal is acceptable.

Comment: The syntax used in jdweng's comment creates an array that is then piped to Foreach and, in Foreach, each element of the array is received as $_.  You could also save the array to a variable such as `$MyVar = 0x00..0xFFF`.